# HTTPS icon red and crossed out using Apache2

Tags: ssl, web, https, apache2

I am trying to use the index.html default website of Apache2 but using secure connection with https.

I am using a self signed certificate but when I get into the website, the "https" is crossed out in red. I would like to fix it without using a paid certificate, since this is only for testing and learning more about Apache2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's because you're using a self-signed certificate and the browser can't verify that your certificate is valid.

This isn't really a "problem" until you expect external visitors to the site, who might be alarmed that you don't have publicly verifiable https.  It's still encrypted, but you can't tell as a user if the connection has been intercepted by a "man in the middle".

You can use letsencrypt.org to easily add a publicly verifiable certificate to a server with a domain name.  If you're using an IP address there's not much you can do.

There are many tutorials for Let's Encrypt that vary depending on the specific platform you're using.

Comment: I have tried let's encrypt but I get this error:
NXDOMAIN looking up A for - check that a DNS record exists for this domain...
my domain is rrraspberry.es The problem is that I am in local so I will not be able to get the certificate?

Comment: Yes, your domain has to be publicly addressable.  If you're not on a public IP address, then don't worry about the certificate.  It's just a warning for the rest of the world.

Answer (score 0):

You can use what mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate) to make your browser consider your local website as a trusted one.

I hope my answer will help you